migration with alembic from database mapping
I'm trying to create an alembic migration out of an existing database with 33 tables, keys, sequences and so on. Since I haven't been using any Alchemy I don't have any metadata and classes describing my DB in Alchemy. for the initial migration with --autogenerate I need the metadata. In a websource I've found a solution where you can pretty easy make a mapping from your database:
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class MigrationMeta:

    Base = automap_base()

    # engine, suppose it has two tables 'user' and 'address' set up
    engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:pass@host/db")
    def __init__(self):
        self.Base.prepare(autoload_with=self.engine, reflect=True)
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)

then I put into env.py:
from api.alchemy_mapping import MigrationMeta 
target_metadata = MigrationMeta.Base.metadata

and start my the autogeneration. Alembic finds all the tables, keys and sequences, but as removed ones:
...
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'user_setting'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'payment_accounts'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'user_tier'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected removed table 'mobule_game'
...

and creates a migration version with the reverse order of changes:
def upgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('bonus_settings')
    op.drop_table('contractor')
    op.drop_index('tokens_token_index', table_name='tokens')
    op.drop_index('tokens_token_token_ip_index', table_name='tokens')
    op.drop_index('tokens_user_id_index', table_name='tokens')
    op.drop_table('tokens')
    op.drop_table('game')
...

def downgrade() -> None:
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('method_access_right',
    sa.Column('id', sa.INTEGER(), server_default=sa.text("nextval('method_access_right_id_seq'::regclass)"), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('method', sa.VARCHAR(length=32), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('project_type', sa.VARCHAR(length=32), autoincrement=False, nullable=False),
    sa.Column('user_role', sa.VARCHAR(length=128), autoincrement=False, nullable=True),
    sa.Column('admin_system', sa.VARCHAR(length=128), autoincrement=False, nullable=False)
    )
...

I've tried to rename these parts manually (upgrade to downgrade, and downgrade to upgrade), but when I do any changes and want to create a new migration it says that the DB is not up to date.
What am I doing wrong?

Your init method is misspelled.. is that a typo?

@RitvikTheGod yes, I'm sorry, just updated it. thank you.
